Expectation of not called girls
There are
$m$  boys &
$n$  girls in the classroom. The teacher calls roll in a random, non-repetitive order until all the boys have been called. What is the expected number of girls who are not called?
I first thought of considering the question as a permutation problem where we need to calculate the expected number of girls after the last boy in queue. But then realize this may be wrong since the teacher just call until all the boys are called instead of the whole class.

We can use indicator variables to solve the question easily.
Let $X_i$ be an indicator r.v. that is equal to $1$ if the $i_{th}$ girl is called before all the  boys are called, and $0$ otherwise.
Consider $(m+1)$ students including the $m$ boys and the $i_{th}$ girl,
then $P(X_i) = \frac{m}{m+1}$
Now the expectation of an indicator variable is just the probability of the event it indicates, thus $\Bbb E[X_i] = \frac{m}{m+1}$
and by linearity of expectation, which operates even when the variables are not independent,
$\Bbb E[X] = \Bbb E[X_1] +\Bbb E[X_2] + ... +\Bbb E[X_n] = \frac{nm}{m+1}$
Thus the expected number of girls not called $= n - \frac{nm}{m+1}$

Your "first thought" works fine. Consider a random ordering of all the children in the class. The positions of the $m$ boys determine $m+1$ groupings of consecutive girls (some of the girl groupings may be empty--wherever there are two consecutive boys). So, the average size of each girl grouping is $\frac{n}{m+1}$. The last girl grouping consists of the girls who are not called in roll call. Hence the expected number of girls not called is $\frac{n}{m+1}$.
By the way, this agrees with true blue anil's answer.
